# Who can build a libssh2.a for iPhone

Tags: iphone, libssh

Who can build a libssh2.a for iPhone
it's something about cross compilation 
I totally Don't know how to Set it rightly

What I want to use is sftp client on iPhone

anybody did this ?
Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to compile libssh2 for iOS by following [these instructions](http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/libssh2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script for building libssh2 for iOS: https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS